# Solve the following limit: $\lim_{n->\infty} n(\frac{\frac{1}{n!}(\frac{n}{e})^n}{\frac{1}{(n+1)!}(\frac{n+1}{e})^{n+1}}-1)$

Tags: limits

I need to find the following limit or at least to be able to compare it with $1$:

$\lim_{n->\infty} n(\frac{\frac{1}{n!}(\frac{n}{e})^n}{\frac{1}{(n+1)!}(\frac{n+1}{e})^{n+1}}-1)$

I did simplifications and I got that the limit is equal to $\lim_{n->\infty}n(e(\frac{n}{n+1})^n-1)$ but I do not know what to do after.

The result in the parentheses is $0$ and we get $\infty*0$ which is indetermined form, but somehow I need to be able to find its value. Can you help me out?

Comment: Are you aware of some form of Stirling's inequality for $n!$?

Comment: What do you know about asymptotic developments ? Put everything on the same denominator, and factor $n^{n+1}$ everywhere, and find an AD of $(1+\frac1n)^{n+1}$. You should find, if my computations are correct, $\frac e2$.

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS I put everything on the same denominator and I got $\lim_{n->\infty}\frac{n^{n+1}(e-(1+\frac{1}{n})^n)}{(n+1)^n}$. Now what?

Comment: @Ghost : $frac{n^{n+1}(e-(1+\frac{1}{n})^n)}{(n+1)^n} = \frac{n(e-e^{n\ln(1+\frac1n)})}{(1+\frac1n)^n}$. Denominator has limit $1$. Numerator is $ne(1-e^{n\ln(1+\frac1n)-1}$. As $1-e^u\sim_{u\to0} -u$, you can conclude with an asymptotic development of $\ln(1+\frac1n)$.

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS The denominator has the limit $e$ not $1$.

Comment: Right, sorry :-(

Answer (score 3):

We are interested in
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty} n\left(\frac{e}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n}-1\right) $$
where
$$ \log\left(1+\tfrac{1}{n}\right)^n = 1-\frac{1+o(1)}{2n} $$
leads by exponentiation to
$$ \left(1+\tfrac{1}{n}\right)^n = e -\frac{e+o(1)}{2n} $$
then to
$$ \frac{e}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n} = 1+\frac{1+o(1)}{2n}, $$
hence the wanted limit is $\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}$.